# How to use SqlDataAdapter in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems my code is not complete or my syntax is wrong but i tried my best to come up with some-kind of solution but with no success so far... so here is what i am trying to do:
I have several drop down box and would like to assign the selected value for each of the drop down box to the values in the table adapter.  Here is my code so far but not sure what is missing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["myID"]);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT NAME, DEPARTMENT, LOCATION from MyTable WHERE ID =  '" + ID + "' ", con);
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    ddl_Name.SelectedValue = dt[0].Name;
    ddl_DEPARTMENT.SelectedValue = dt[0].DEPARTMENT;
    ddl_LOCATION.SelectedValue = dt[0].LOCATION;
}
```

my problem starts here when i type dt[0].Name, it seems it does not like when i add the zero.  Pls help.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dt` is the `DataTable` which has no indexer, you want the `DataRow`s field, so you need to get the row first via `DataTable.Rows[index]`:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
    ddl_Name.SelectedValue = row.Field<string>("Name");
    ddl_DEPARTMENT.SelectedValue = row.Field<string>("DEPARTMENT");
    ddl_LOCATION.SelectedValue = row.Field<string>("LOCATION");
}
```

You cannot access the field directly (without a strongly typed `DataTable`). You have to use `DataRow.Field` to get the value of a field or the old weakly typed indexer:

```
object name = row["Name"];
```

- Apart from that, you should not use string concatenation to build your sql query. You are open for **sql injetion** via url parameters. Use sql-parameters to prevent that.
- I assume you are using `ViewState`(default), then put this code block in a `!IsPostBack` check, otherwise the `SelectedIndexChanged` event  will not trigger since the user-selection will be overwritten from the old database value.

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["myID"]);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT NAME, DEPARTMENT, LOCATION from MyTable WHERE ID =  @ID", con);
        DataTable dt= new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(ID));
        da.Fill(dt);
        // Code above... 
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, your solution worked and i appreciate u teaching me some extra staff.  thnks